# How do you perform double-SHA-256 encoding?

Tags: hash, sha256

The Bitcoin [Protocol-specification](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#Hashes) gives an example of double-SHA-256 encoding.

> hello
>   2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824 (first round of sha-256)
>   9595c9df90075148eb06860365df33584b75bff782a510c6cd4883a419833d50 (second round of sha-256)

I've tried various SHA256 [calculators](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator) and the first encoding matches no problem, but the second always resolves to

> d7914fe546b684688bb95f4f888a92dfc680603a75f23eb823658031fff766d9

I've also tried UPPERCASE and swapping the byte endianness.

Comment: Just semantics, but to avoid a common misunderstanding: sha256 does **hashing**, not encoding. Encoding is something entirely different. For one it implies it can be decoded, whereas hashing is strictly a one-way (and destructive) operation.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're hashing the hexadecimal representation of the first hash. You need to hash the actual hash -- the binary data that the hex represents.

Try this:

```
$ echo -n hello |openssl dgst -sha256 -binary |openssl dgst -sha256
```

Comment: This seems right, but how did the first round work when hashing the ASCII string "HELLO" vs the binary representation of ASCII hello?

Comment: @makerofthings7 "HELLO" is binary. H is a byte with value 72, E is 69, etc. A raw, binary hash can also be printed, but many of its characters are likely to be invisible control characters, so it's generally written in hex. I can also write "HELLO" in hex: it's 48454c4c4f.

Comment: @makerofthings7: There is no difference between "the ASCII string 'HELLO' and "the binary representation of ASCII 'HELLO'". However, there is a difference between the ASCII representation of a number in hexadecimal and that number in binary.

Comment: theymos and @DavidSchwartz it all makes perfect sense now. thanks

Comment: Hi, there are an optimized (direct and faster) option to perform SHA256d? Some `openssl` or similar (reliable) optimized algorith for it?

Answer (score 8):

You want to work with the digests, not the hex strings.

Here's some Ruby:

```ruby
require 'digest'
d = Digest::SHA2.new 256
d2 = Digest::SHA2.new 256
d << 'hello'
d.to_s
d2 << d.digest
d2.to_s
```

This will be the output from `irb`:

```ruby
1.9.3p194 :001 > require 'digest'
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :003 >   d = Digest::SHA2.new 256
 => #<Digest::SHA2:256 e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855> 
1.9.3p194 :004 > d2 = Digest::SHA2.new 256
 => #<Digest::SHA2:256 e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855> 
1.9.3p194 :005 > d << 'hello'
 => #<Digest::SHA2:256 2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824> 
1.9.3p194 :006 > d.to_s
 => "2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824" 
1.9.3p194 :007 > d2 << d.digest
 => #<Digest::SHA2:256 9595c9df90075148eb06860365df33584b75bff782a510c6cd4883a419833d50> 
1.9.3p194 :008 > d2.to_s
 => "9595c9df90075148eb06860365df33584b75bff782a510c6cd4883a419833d50"
```

Here's the same thing in Python:

```py
import hashlib
d = hashlib.sha256(b"hello")
d2 = hashlib.sha256()
d.hexdigest()
d2.update(d.digest())
d2.hexdigest()
```

And the output from within a Python shell:

```py
>>> d = hashlib.sha256(b"hello")
>>> d2 = hashlib.sha256()
>>> d.hexdigest()
'2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824'
>>> d2.update(d.digest())
>>> d2.hexdigest()
'9595c9df90075148eb06860365df33584b75bff782a510c6cd4883a419833d50'
```

Comment: thanks for code samples. I later found the Python code on the wiki, but still couldn't understand what made it work. +1

Answer (score 5):

For the second round of sha256, you need to hash the raw binary output from the first round, not the textual version.

A sha256 hash is 256 bits, or 32 bytes. Thus for the second round you should be hashing a piece of data that's 32 bytes. When hashing a hexadecimal string as the literal input for the second round, your data is 64 bytes.

Try a hashing tool that can interpret hexadecimal input. For example [see here](http://anyhash.com/sha256?hello), copy/paste the hash to the input field and check the 'Hex' checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

For easy reference, lets name the various inputs and outputs from your question like so:

```
pre-image 1:                     hello
                                   |
                                   v
hash operation 1:                SHA256
                                   |
                                   v
hash output 1 (aka pre-image 2): 2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824
                                   |
                                   v
hash operation 2:                SHA256
                                   |
                                   v
hash output 2:                   9595c9df90075148eb06860365df33584b75bff782a510c6cd4883a419833d50
```

Pre-image 1 is binary (ASCII) data. We know this because the range of hexadecimal characters is `0-9` and `a-f`, and there are characters beyond `f` in pre-image 1. So hash operation 1 must be performed using a binary input.

By definition, a SHA256 hash operation always produces a 256 bit integer. We typically represent this in hexadecimal format, however it could just as correctly be written in decimal format and nothing would change:

```
hex:     2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824
decimal: 20329878786436204988385760252021328656300425018755239228739303522659023427620
```

[(Decimal conversion using Wolfram Alpha)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0x2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824)

Since we know that pre-image 2 is a hexadecimal number, then hash operation 2 must be performed upon a number, rather than upon binary data.

In Javascript, using the [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl), the two hashes would be done like so:

```
var preImage1 = 'hello';
var hashOutput1 = sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(preImage1);
console.log('hash output 1: ' + sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(hashOutput1));
var preImage2 = hashOutput1;
var hashOutput2 = sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(preImage2);
console.log('hash output 2: ' + sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(hashOutput2));
```

The SJCL is clever enough to figure out the pre-image formats and perform the hash correctly in each case.

You can also do these hash operations live on my blog, here: https://analysis.null.place/how-do-the-bitcoin-mining-algorithms-work/#form10

Note how the hash output changes when you click the *pre-image is hexadecimal* checkbox (this only works when hexadecimal characters are present in the input).

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but here is a Node.js implementation using the built-in `crypto` module:

```javascript
const crypto = require('crypto');
/**
 *
 * @param {Buffer} data
 * @returns {Buffer}
 */
function doubleSHA256(data) {
  return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(crypto.createHash('sha256').update(data).digest()).digest();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.....

Had to make slight modifications to the **`ParseHex()`** provided by [Andrew Chow](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/48884/andrew-chow)....

### Headers needed are:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <assert.h> // assert() is used
```

**Sha256 implementation in use is the one provided by [Zedwood](http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-sha256-function) !!**

First is the **`ParseHex`** function provided by [Andrew Chow](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/48884/andrew-chow)

```cpp
std::string ParseHex(std::string& s)
{
    assert(s.size() % 2 == 0);
    static const std::size_t symbol_count = 256;
    static const unsigned char hex_to_bin[symbol_count] = 
    {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x00 - 0x07
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x08 - 0x0F
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x10 - 0x17
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x18 - 0x1F
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x20 - 0x27
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x28 - 0x2F
        0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, // 0x30 - 0x37
        0x08, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x38 - 0x3F
        0x00, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x00, // 0x40 - 0x47
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x48 - 0x4F
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x50 - 0x57
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x58 - 0x5F
        0x00, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x00, // 0x60 - 0x67
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x68 - 0x6F
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x70 - 0x77
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x78 - 0x7F
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x80 - 0x87
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x88 - 0x8F
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x90 - 0x97
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x98 - 0x9F
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xA0 - 0xA7
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xA8 - 0xAF
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xB0 - 0xB7
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xB8 - 0xBF
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xC0 - 0xC7
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xC8 - 0xCF
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xD0 - 0xD7
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xD8 - 0xDF
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xE0 - 0xE7
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xE8 - 0xEF
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xF0 - 0xF7
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00  // 0xF8 - 0xFF
    };

    std::string out;
    auto itr = s.begin();
    while (itr != s.end())
    {
       unsigned char b = static_cast<unsigned char>(hex_to_bin[*(itr++)] << 4);
       b |= static_cast<unsigned char>(hex_to_bin[*(itr++)]     );
       out.push_back(b);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Then next is the modified **`sha256`** function call.

```cpp
std::string sha256(std::string input)
{
    string kk;
    int size = input.length();
    
    unsigned char header_data[size], hash[32];// header_data is "160" in size because midstate optimization is not implemented
    char buf[2*32+1];
    buf[2*32] = 0;

    input = ParseHex(input); // ParseHex() is UNDEFINED !!!
    init(); // Initiialize
    update((unsigned char*)input.c_str(), input.length()); // Update
    final(hash); // Finalize

    // Uncomment code below if you want to directly double hash input data using a single "sha256(input)" function call
    // init();
    // update(hash, 32);
    // final(hash);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) 
        sprintf(buf+i*2, "%02x", hash[i]); // feed data from hash into buf and format data

    return std::string(buf); // Return buf as string instead of char
}
```

- **THESE FUNCTIONS NEED TO BE PASTED INSIDE THE SHA256 HEADER FILE**
- **YOU'D HAVE TO REVERSE ENDIANESS OF HASH RESULT.**
- **ALSO, THE "assert()" THROWS AN ERROR FOR UNEVEN LENGTHED INPUTS.. SO "abc" WON'T WORK.**

Hope this helps you if you ever need this....

Cheers!!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have coded your algo to always assume that
your input msg always contains data in ASCII display format.
That would explain why your first algo produced the correct
hash table.
For run2, you can have your input msg data in any format you
like, as long as you have some way of telling your algo what
to expect.
I am going to assume that when you wrote your algo, that you
coded it to always expect ASCII display format in the input
msg file.
So, if you didn't switch your first output block table to
ASCII display format, then that would explain why you didn't
get the expected final block table from your second run.
Grab a list of "The IBM PC Character Set" and you'll see
what I mean.
eg if you're providing an 'a' and it's really a hexadecimal 'a'
as opposed to a ASCII display format 'a', then you've GOT to
let your algo know what you are doing - it can't second guess
that you've switched formats without telling it.
So similarly, you may have put the hexadecimal hash or even
the binary hash table, from run1 output into run2 input,
which is fine, BUT you have let your algo know that it
should read it as what ever format you picked, to wack into
the run2 input file.
There are 2 ways to fix this IMO.
(1) convert your output hash block table from run1, to ASCII
display chars and wack them into the run2 input file.
I wouldn't do this because you get some wierd and wonderful
ASCII display chars that may do wierd things.
(2) Re-code your algo, so that you can tell it what data
will be coming at it, from the run2 input file.
That's a more flexible way to do things, and it opens up a
lot more options in terms of using any base you like, even
your own custom ones, but YMMV.
A lot of water has passed under the bridge since your problem
was published, but this may help others.